# golang template.JS to string and template.HTML to string

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm using "html/template".

How do I convert the value of a **template.JS** object to a string? What about **template.HTML**?

I have a struct where I store some js scripts and css code/files, such as: "HeaderCSS", "FooterJS". I load them to the header/footer of my templates. The problem is that I need to check if they are loaded, so I won't load the same script twice (each reload means a new script load) because I'm using append, in order to be able to insert multiple scripts. In this way, each refresh will append the scripts to the existing scripts.

My idea is to check if they are allready loaded in order to prevent loading them multiple times. I was thinking about using **strings.Contains()** function. But I can't do that since I don't know to convert templates.HTML and templates.JS to string.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Per the documentation, they're strings](https://golang.org/pkg/html/template/#JS). Just type cast to string:

```
asStr := string(myTplJsObj)
```

Comment: shame to me :), I was trying: "string.(myObj)" and "myObj.(string)"

Comment: @Pascut that format is a type assertion, not a type cast. Type assertions can only be done on `interface`s.

Comment: The second is a type assertion, the first is just invalid.